# Creating a matrix of differences from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame [10 Rows and 1 Column (C)]

```
df = data.ix[0:9, 0]
```

I want to create a matrix which shows the distance between each of the elements [10 Rows and 10 Columns] like so:

```
C0 - C0   C1-C0  …  Cn-C0
C0 - C1   C1-C1  …  Cn-C1
C0 - C2   C1-C2  …  Cn-C2
 …    …     …    …   …
C0 - C9   C1-C9  …  Cn-Cn
```

I know this could be done (inefficiently) with for two `for` loops. What would a better way be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values of a DataFrame or Series into a NumPy array with the `.values` method, e.g.:

```
df.C.values
```

To create your matrix, you can subtract the array `df.C` from itself like this:

```
df.C.values - df.C.values[:, np.newaxis] # also see @immerrr's comment
```

Which creates a NumPy array with the desired values.

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'C': range(5)})   
   C
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

>>> df.C.values - df.C.values[:, np.newaxis]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: It's better to use `df.C.values[:, np.newaxis]` instead of `np.vstack(df.C.values)`.  One thing is that in general case you can add multiple axes with in one take, e.g. `x[...,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]`, another is that vstack is linear in array size (and slow): with `x = np.arange(100000)`,  `%timeit np.vstack(x)` gives `1 loops, best of 3: 342 ms per loop` while `%timeit x[:,np.newaxis]` gives `1000000 loops, best of 3: 954 ns per loop`

Comment: @immerrr Thanks for the suggestion and timings. I've edited the answer to acknowledge the benefits of using `np.newaxis`.